# Assignment asking to use grep command, how would I write a command when it is fine with the find command?

Tags: linux, unix

My Intro to OS teacher wants me to enter a command that long lists the /etc directory and finds all files modified or created with the size of 4096 bytes.

My answer is simply `find /etc -size 4k -ls`.

How am I supposed to use the grep command to do this? It seems kind of pointless...

Comment: Probably `ls -l /etc | grep ...`, but I like your command better.

Comment: This would be very tricky with `grep`, because if you just use `grep 4096`, it will match that anywhere on the line, so it will include files with `4096` in the name. But I suspect your teacher doesn't care about such unlikely matches.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. Try SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

It sure makes no sense but in IT you kind of get used to insane seeming requirements so here is one:

```
$ ls -l /etc | grep "^-\([^ ]* *\)\{4\}4096 "
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root            4096 Oct 27  2014 wgetrc
```

- `^-` it's a file (`^d` for dir etc.)
- `[^ ]* *` field and delimiting space(s)
- `\(...\)\{4\}` four times previous, ie. filesize is in the fifth field
- `4096` filesize. Notice the trailing space to limit the size exactly to 4096.